# Rotating a canvas object around the mouse cursor

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I am trying to replicate this effect: http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/trail/03/

I have this as a Particle constructor:

```
function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = 4;
    this.color = '#f0f';
    this.speed = 15;
    this.angle = 0;
}
```

And I'm using this loop to animate all particle instances:

```
for (var i = 0, len = particles.length; i < len; i++) {
    var dx = mouse.x - particles[i].x,
        dy = mouse.y - particles[i].y,
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    particles[i].vx = Math.cos(angle) * particles[i].speed;
    particles[i].vy = Math.sin(angle) * particles[i].speed;
    particles[i].x += particles[i].vx;
    particles[i].y += particles[i].vy;
    particles[i].draw(ctx);
}
```

The particles follow the mouse, but reach the cursor and start flickering around it, which is not a desired behaviour. I'd like to circle around the cursor, as in the example.. The interesting part is that if I set the particle.speed to something like 30 and add 1000 to the angle, the particles rotate around the cursor, but really fast and ruin the effect...

You can see a live example here: http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/EwafI

All suggestions are more then welcome, thanks in advance!

P.S. I know that the code for the pointed example is easily findable, but I'm relatively new to javascript and I'm not that good at reading other people code and can't quite understand the logic behind it..

Answer (score 0):

Currently the target of your particles is the mouse cursor. But that's not the target you want. You want a target that's moving around your cursor. And you want for every particle a different target, so they don't hover all at the same place.

There are also some other things that the original does and you don't:

- in the original, the particle speed depends on the distance to the target
- it seems they can't change the direction instantly, but change the direction of their movement relatively slowly.

Comment: So, should I generate another set of invisible targets that rotate around the cursor and set them as the target to the particles?

I will tackle the particle speed and the change of direction as soon as I get them to rotate around the cursor...

Comment: Yes. Currently your target is mouse.x/mouse.y. But it should be something like mouse.x+Math.cos(time/factor)*radius / mouse.y+Math.sin(time/factor)*radius. You can get time from the requestAnimationFrame callback, should be the first argument. Try factor = 2*Math.PI/4000 for a rotation every 4s. I also noticed that you do not use time at all, so the actual speed depends on the browser's refresh rate. You should determine the time difference between two invocations and take that into account for the particle's speed per frame.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Tim, but can you explain this equations in a bit more detail? Why would I use time and factor?

Comment: I assume you want a certain number of rotations per minute, and for that you need to bind the rotation angle to some time reference. The factor is needed to convert the time, which is usually given in ms since some point in time, to the angle. An alternative way would be to work with time differences, like dt ms passed and then you convert it into the difference in angle. This may be the more natural approach, but it sometimes more fragile, when your script is not invoked in regular intervals. Not much of a difference in a interactive simulations though.

Comment: But why would my rotation have anything to do with time? I will tackle each particle's speed to the target using easing (like vx = Math.sin(angle) * particle.speed ) and it will be separated from the rotation movement.

Basically, as far as I understand, I need another set of invisible particles rotating around the cursor. THEN, I will use their x and y to as target of the moving particles. The million dollar quiestion I guess is how to rotate the invisible particles around the cursor?

Comment: Currently you move the particle by particle.speed every time your requestAnimationFrame() callback is invoked. But how often will it be invoked? That's up to the browser, and almost random. On a very slow system it may be once per second, and on a fast one 60 times or more. Every time it is invoked, you move by particle.speed. So the speed will be different on every system, and may even change with system load.

Comment: Thanks, but still my main question - rotating the particles around the cursor is unanswered...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64007/discussion-between-tim-jansen-and-georgi-b-nikolov). Got an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EAmhD